# How do I change a users nick name using Discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am using the following code to register the slash command:

```js
const nick = new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName('nick')
  .setDescription('Change the nickname of a user')
  .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.ChangeNickname)
  .addUserOption((option) =>
    option
      .setName('user')
      .setDescription('The user to change the nickname')
      .setRequired(true),
  )
  .addStringOption((option) =>
    option.setName('nickname').setDescription('New nickname for the user'),
  );
```

The logic:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) =>{
  if (interaction.commandName === 'nick') {
    const user = interaction.options.getUser('user');
    const name = interaction.options.getString('nickname');
    user.setNickname(name);
  }
});
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
   user.setNickname(name)
         ^

TypeError: user.setNickname is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `interaction.user` is a `User`, not a `GuildMember` and only members have the `setNickname()` method.

You should get the member instead of the user. Try something like this:

```js
const member = await interaction.options.getMember('user')
user.setNickname(name)
```